# Testing request.resolver_match in a Django context_processor

Tags: django, django-testing

I have a Django context processor that puts the name of the current URL into the template context:

```py
def url_name(request):
    url_name = False
    if request.resolver_match:
        url_name = request.resolver_match.url_name
    return {"url_name": url_name}
```

This works - if I visit `/` then `{{ url_name }}` in the template will display "home" because I have a URL pattern like:

```py
path("", HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),
```

I would like to write a unittest for this context processor. I could do it like this:

```py
from django.test import Client, RequestFactory, TestCase
from myapp.context_processors import url_name

class URLNameTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_url_name(self):
        response = Client().get("/")
        self.assertEqual(response.context["url_name"], "home")
```

That succeeds, but I'd like to unitttest the `url_name()` method on its own, outside of the response cycle.

I've tried this:

```py
class URLNameTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_url_name(self):
        request = RequestFactory().get("/")
        context = url_name(request)
        self.assertEqual(context["url_name"], "home")
```

But that fails because, in this situation, within `url_name()`, `request.resolver_match` is `None`. Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since you try to get urlname by urlpath you should link your request with some view, you can do it to set  "resolver_match" attribute like that:

```
from django.urls import resolve

...

class URLNameTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_url_name(self):
        request = RequestFactory().get("/")
        request.resolver_match = resolve("/")
...
```

You create a request using a RequestFactory but it doesn't mean that your request is linked with any view,  to link your request with some view you need to set resolver_match to your request.

Read more:

[Link 1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve)

[Link 2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-respons/#django.http.HttpRequest.resolver_match)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't quite follow. `request.resolver_match` is being used in the function I'm testing, not in the test itself.

Comment: i edited my answer to adding more explanation

Comment: Thank you, I almost understand now, and I got the test working as expected.

Comment: really late to the party, but is there a way to get APIRequestFatory to set the resolver_match for us? I kinda have to create a request, then set the request.resolver_match using resolve function and really would like an automated way of doing it. vote up for your answer though, it fixed my problem for now.